# add sku to many page in shopify

Tags: html, shopify

I need to add the SKU in 2000 pages in a website of shopify. I know that you can use the html code to do it, however, I did not mention it, if you could help me, I would appreciate it.

This is the way it should be:

[image]

This is the data that should be called:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add {{ current_variant.sku }} to your liquid file (probably product-template.liquid) in the place you want it to show up.